# What is the closest you can get to introducing and discharging hypotheses in metamath?

Tags: metamath

How close can you get to introducing and discharging hypotheses in metamath?

I'm trying to define a symbol formal system for the $\land$-only fragment of classical propositional logic.

It has the following rules.

$$ \frac{A \;\;\text{and}\;\; B}{A \land B} \;\;\text{and}\;\; \frac{A\land B}{A} \;\; \text{and} \;\; \frac{A \land B}{B} \;\; \text{are the inference rules} $$

I'm interested in proving a simple statement $P \land Q \vdash Q \land P$.

Here's my attempt to prove it so far in `metamath`. It is semi-syntactically correct, failing at the `verify proof` step in the command line interface.

I'm working using [demo0.mm](https://github.com/metamath/set.mm/blob/develop/demo0.mm) as an example.

Here's what I have so far.

```
$( define 1 (top) 0 (bottom) and * (conjunction)
   Also define |- entailment $)

$c 1 0 * wff |- ( ) $.

$( define metavariables P,Q,R $)

$v P Q R $.

wff-P $f wff P $.
wff-Q $f wff Q $.
wff-R $f wff R $.

wff-conj-P-Q $a wff ( * P Q ) $.

$( inference rule 1: conjunction intro:

   A and B
   -------
    * A B
$)

${
   conj-intro-min  $e |- P $.
   conj-intro-maj  $e |- Q $.
   conj-intro      $a |- ( * P Q ) $.
$}

$( inference rules 2 and 3 : conjunction elim $)

${
   pi1-prem   $e |- ( * P Q ) $.
   pi1        $a |- P $.
$}
${
   pi2-prem   $e |- ( * P Q ) $.
   pi2        $a |- Q $.
$}

$( prove that ( ( * P Q ) ) |- ( * Q P ) $)
commutative-conj $p ( ( * P Q ) ) |- ( * Q P ) $=
wff-P
wff-Q
wff-conj-P-Q
$.
```

The proof of `commutative-conj` is very, very incomplete and does not work.

I know that metamath is vaguely Hilbert-style and ... I'm pretty sure I can't just introduce a hypothesis.

So, I tried to do the next best thing and write a rule that contains a free variable in its conclusion that wouldn't unify with anything.

```
$( An extremely weak form of monotonicity of entailment

If  |- A  holds, then  B |- A  holds.

$)
${
   weak-mono-entailment-prem $e       |- P $.
   weak-mono-entailment      $a ( Q ) |- P $.
$}
```

However, this approach seems to require me to assert more and more *ad hoc* facts about $\vdash$ in order to make any progress at all ...

Is there a better, more idiomatic way to mimic introduction and discharge of hypotheses?

Comment: If it helps, I completely rewrote my answer to get more to your core issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I rewrote my answer, but still I don't really know Metamath per se.  I'm just going off of your logic.  If you tell me I'm completely misunderstanding, I'll delete my answer.**

So far it looks like you have implemented the following three rules:

```
|- P    |- Q        |- ( * P Q )        |- ( * P Q )
------------        ------------        ------------
 |- ( * P Q )          |- P                |- Q
```

and you are trying to prove

```
----------------------
( * Q P ) |- ( * P Q )
```

This is not possible since all of your rules have nothing on the left side of `|-`.

Using your axioms, you can however prove this:

```
|- ( * P Q )
------------
|- ( * Q P )
```

Based on a bit of Googling, I think you would write this theorem as:

```
${
  commutative-conj.1  $e |- ( * P Q )$.
  commutative-conj  $p |- ( * Q P )$= ...
}$
```

However, if you really want exactly `( * P Q ) |- ( * Q P )` you can use a different axiom system which let's you put hypotheses on the left.  Here is a common one, which you can find in [my course notes](http://www.personal.psu.edu/jmr71/teaching/Spring-2016-Math-457/handouts/natural%20deduction%20handout%203.pdf).  You currently only need the rules:

```
          R |- P    R |- Q       R |- ( * P Q )       R |- ( * P Q )
------    ----------------       --------------       ------------
P |- P     R |- ( * P Q )        R |- P               R |- Q
```

Then you start with the assumption rule `(* P Q) |- (* P Q)`.
From that you apply your two elimination rules to get `(* P Q) |- P` and `(* P Q) |- Q`.  Then you put those together with your intro rule to get `(* P Q) |- (* Q P)`.  However, that is just having exactly one hypothesis on the left which isn't what you want in the long run.  I don't know how to deal in MM with an arbitrary list of them.  Another expert can answer that.

Comment: That's great! Reuse the mechanism used for expressing an inference rule to express a conditional theorem (/ derivable inference rule I guess). I'm starting to think that, in metamath, `|-` may really be a dummy symbol whose sole job is to force the expression to begin with a terminal symbol.

Comment: An examination of [set.mm (warning, 41M file)](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metamath/set.mm/develop/set.mm) reveals that this is indeed the case. Thanks again.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet The turnstile `|-` can indeed be seen some kind of marker. In this minimal database, there are two such type codes: `wff` , which means "is a well-formed formula", not giving any assessment about its provability, and `|-` , which means "is provable".

Answer (score 8):

#### Concerning your actual proof attempt:

Here is the completed proof:

```
${
   commutative-conj-prem $e |- ( * P Q ) $.
   $( prove that ( ( * P Q ) ) |- ( * Q P ) $)
   commutative-conj $p |- ( * Q P ) $=
     wff-Q wff-P wff-P wff-Q commutative-conj-prem pi2 wff-P wff-Q
     commutative-conj-prem pi1 conj-intro $.
$}
```

Jason has already explained the changes needed to the theorem statement itself.

Here is how the Metamath program displays the proof:

```
MM-PA> SHOW PROOF commutative-conj
 5     pi2-prem=commutative-conj-prem $e |- ( * P Q )
 6   conj-intro-min=pi2             $a |- Q
 9     pi1-prem=commutative-conj-prem $e |- ( * P Q )
10   conj-intro-maj=pi1             $a |- P
11 commutative-conj=conj-intro    $a |- ( * Q P )
```

- Step 5, it invokes `commutative-conj-prem`,
- Step 6, it invokes `pi2`, with step 5 as a premise,
- Step 9, it invokes again `commutative-conj-prem`,
- Step 10, it invokes `pi1`, with step 9 as a premise,
- Step 11, if finally invokes `conj-intro`, with steps 6 and 10 as premises.

You'll notice some steps are not shown. These are used to build the expressions which are used as substitutions. In your case, those are invocations of `wff-p` and `wff-q`. They can be shown using the `SHOW PROOF commutative-conj / ALL` command.

Here is the way the proof can be built with `metamath-exe`:

```
MM> PROVE commutative-conj
Entering the Proof Assistant.  HELP PROOF_ASSISTANT for help, EXIT to exit.
You will be working on statement (from "SHOW STATEMENT commutative-conj"):
21 commutative-conj-prem $e |- ( * P Q ) $.
22 commutative-conj $p |- ( * Q P ) $= ... $.
Unknown step summary (from "SHOW NEW_PROOF / UNKNOWN"):
1    commutative-conj=? $? |- ( * Q P )
MM-PA> ASSIGN 1 conj-intro
3 -1   conj-intro-min=?            $? |- Q
4      conj-intro-maj=?            $? |- P
MM-PA> ASSIGN 3 pi2
5 -1     pi2-prem=?                  $? |- ( * $4 Q )
7      conj-intro-maj=?            $? |- P
MM-PA> ASSIGN 5 commutative-conj-prem
7      conj-intro-maj=?               $? |- P
MM-PA> ASSIGN 7 pi1
 9        pi1-prem=?                     $? |- ( * P $6 )
MM-PA> ASSIGN 9 commutative-conj-prem
MM-PA> IMPROVE ALL
A proof of length 1 was found for step 8.
A proof of length 1 was found for step 7.
A proof of length 1 was found for step 4.
A proof of length 1 was found for step 3.
A proof of length 1 was found for step 2.
A proof of length 1 was found for step 1.
Steps 1 and above have been renumbered.
CONGRATULATIONS!  The proof is complete.  Use SAVE NEW_PROOF to save it.
Note:  The Proof Assistant does not detect $d violations.  After saving
the proof, you should verify it with VERIFY PROOF.
```

(this is the full output, the necessary commands are those after the interactive prompt `MM-PA>`)

#### More generally:

If you would like a proof format which has hypotheses one the left, before the turnstile, it is also possible to define it, see for example Mario's [HOL database](https://github.com/metamath/set.mm/blob/develop/hol.mm), where your statement would be written something like:

```
ancom $p |- ( R , S ) |= ( S , R ) $=
```

That's probably as close as you can get.

In practice, in the `set.mm` database, it common to use a "deduction style" format for proofs, where the implication `->` takes the role of the inference rules, and a generic `ph` takes the role of the context. Then [pm3.22](http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/pm3.22.html) would correspond to your theorem. Its statement is written:

```
pm3.22 $p |- ( ( ph /\ ps ) -> ( ps /\ ph ) ) $=
```

But of course, from a proof theoretical point of view, that's a different statement.